# How to protect nginx proxy from being spoofed by other reverse proxies?

Tags: nginx, security, reverse-proxy

I've recently noticed that one of my sites that's running behind nginx proxy became accessible via bunch of random domains. Some of them are proxies generated by sites like http://unblocksit.es and similar. These are mostly harmless, however there are proxies that inject adds and others that look like they are aimed to intercept users credentials.

I know I could block them by IP but it's constant race and I'll be always the one that has to catch up. Are there any other mechanism that could be applied to prevent nginx from being accessed via reverse proxy?

Comment: Use HTTPS and use strict transport security. That will deal with some of them, but there's really nothing much you can do that such malicious sites can't counter.